# Laravel change column to nullable

Tags: migration, laravel-5

I have an application where I have created a migration and now I need to change one column to nullable. For that I am using this new migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('Tablename', function ($table) {  
        $table->string('nickname')->nullable()->change();
        $table->text('message', 5000)->change(); 
       });   
}
```

When I am running migration I am getting this error:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "Tablename" does not exis
  t (SQL: ALTER TABLE Wechat ALTER nickname DROP NOT NULL)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "tablename" does not exis
  t
```

I am using postgres as my db and I am using laravel 5.2